# insert String array as label content in datagrid row in next window through radio button C# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have written some code for inserting label at runtime having its content set to a string array and then insert that label into a datagrid row . All of this will initiate when certain radiobuttons are checked. code is working perfectly fine. but all this can be done in a same window. I dont know what to do when the datagrid is on another window so edited question is as follows:

**EDITED:**

what if i say that datagrid is on another window. and i have to fill that datagrid through this form. I know how to transfer label content from one window to another but i dont know how to do it in case of datagrid. Particularly in this case.

**Xaml Code:**

```
    <Grid>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb_1" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="1" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb_2" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="1"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb_3" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,120,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="1"  />
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,159,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="2" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb_4" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,179,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="2"/>
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,199,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="2" />
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="713,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_2"/>
    <DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="549,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="253" Width="399" />
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,226,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="3" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb_6" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,246,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="3"/>
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,266,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="3" />
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,298,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="4" />
    <RadioButton x:Name="rb_8" Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,318,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="4"/>
    <RadioButton Content="RadioButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="351,338,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" GroupName="4" />

</Grid>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    DataTable dt;
    DataRow dr;
    string[] str = new string[4];
    int location = 0;
    int count = 0;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dt = new DataTable("emp");
        DataColumn dc1 = new DataColumn("Factors", typeof(string));
        DataColumn dc2 = new DataColumn("Non_Compliant", typeof(string));

        dt.Columns.Add(dc1);
        dt.Columns.Add(dc2);

        datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
    }
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (count >= 1)
        {
            datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            dt.Clear();
        }

        str[0] = "Load Path1";
        str[1] = "Load Path2";
        str[2] = "Load Path3";
        str[3] = "Load Path4";
        int j = 0;

        if (rb_2.IsChecked == true)
        {
            j = 0;
            int k = 0;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Height = 28;
            label.Width = 100;
            label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            label.Content = str[j];
            dr[k] = label.Content;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            location += 34;

        }
        if (rb_4.IsChecked == true)
        {
            j = 1;
            int k = 0;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Height = 28;
            label.Width = 100;
            label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            label.Content = str[j];
            dr[k] = label.Content;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            location += 34;

        }
        if (rb_6.IsChecked == true)
        {
            j = 2;
            int k = 0;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Height = 28;
            label.Width = 100;
            label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            label.Content = str[j];
            dr[k] = label.Content;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            location += 34;

        }
        if (rb_8.IsChecked == true)
        {
            j = 3;
            int k = 0;
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            Label label = new Label();
            label.Height = 28;
            label.Width = 100;
            label.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            label.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
            label.Content = str[j];
            dr[k] = label.Content;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            datagrid_.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
            location += 34;
        }
        count++;

    }


}
```

}

Comment: You should probably better ask the on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Vanadium90 Before you post to [codereview.se], please be sure to read the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) and make sure your question is on topic there.

Comment: Your code is completely wrong and horrible, if that's what you're asking. Delete all that monstrosity and use proper DataBinding.

Comment: i am in learning phase. No body is born a programmer. thanks. Any good book on databinding topic u recommend for a newbie? coz i tried to find it quite difficult to grasp databinding.